# Git create a blank merge commit keeping all current changes and exit merge

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I want to merge `master/main` branch into my `feature` branch.

There are conflicts.

I resolved all the conflicts by `keep current changes` and there are no changes to commit.

But I am still stuck in `MERGING` mode as I have no changes to commit in the merge commit

How do I create a blank merge commit or exit the `MERGING` mode without any commit but marking the master branch as merged?

Comment: It sounds like you effectively overwrote all changes in every commit that you didn't have yet. It's possible that's desired, but normally that would be unusual. It would almost be like reverting every one else's commits first and then making your changes. (Effectively saying you don't like anyone else's changes and are going to redo them all.)

Comment: Side Note: if you know that you don't want the changes from the new commits you are merging in, you could do something like this: `git merge -s ours main`. That will merge in the commit IDs but ignore all of the changes, like you did. I'm not sure that you could have known that would be the end result though, until you tried it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am still stuck in MERGING mode

You must [finalize](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) the merge after the conflicts have been resolved.

```
git add --all
git merge --continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `vscode` to create a blank commit and it did not allow me to create a blank commit.

I ran `git commit -m "message"` and it created the blank merge commit